# Why does 'foo' return an empty body?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

For some reason, `foo` always returns an empty body:

```
internal static async Task<string> Foo(HttpContext context)
{
    var response = await Task.Run(() => { return "response"; });
    return response;
}

internal static async Task<string> Bar(HttpContext context, string someParam)
{
    var response = await Task.Run(() => { return "response"; });
    return response;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: Adding mapping:
app.MapPost("/Foo", Handlers.Foo);
app.MapPost("/Bar", Handlers.Bar);

Comment: I've noticed that Foo is tinted yellow and Bar is tinted white in the mappings

Comment: @ŁukaszKomosa I have a bug that one api function is not returning anything. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: @Rivo R. That doesn't explain why **Bar** does return the response. You'll have to add these functions to a .Net 6 minimal web api project to reproduce the problem. I think it's a framework bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the behaviour. Moving the handler with the single parameter of `HttpContext` into a separate method leads to the empty response:

```cs
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
WebApplication app = builder.Build();
app.Map("/Fails", Fails);
app.Map("/Fails1", Fails1);
app.Map("/Works", async (HttpContext c) =>
{
    var response = await Task.Run(() => { return "response"; });
    return response;
});
app.Map("/WorksToo", Works);
app.Map("/WorksToo1", Works1);
app.Map("/WorksToo2", Works2);
app.Run();

static async Task<string> Fails1(HttpContext context)
{
    var response = await Task.FromResult("response");
    return response;
}

public partial class Program
{
    internal static async Task<string> Fails(HttpContext context) => await Task.FromResult("response");

    internal static async Task<string> Works(HttpContext context, string someParam) => await Task.FromResult("response");

    internal static async Task<string> Works1(HttpContext context, ILogger<Program> _) => await Task.FromResult("response");

    internal static async Task<string> Works2(HttpRequest context) => await Task.FromResult("response");
}
```

I submitted a new issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39956). For now, you can add a dummy parameter (for example, `CancelationToken`) to the handler as I do with `Works1`.

***Update 1***

The issue was fixed and everything should work as expected in .NET 7.

***Update 2***

The issue was introduced back by some following changes and actually got worse. Follow [the new issue at GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45373).

Comment: Thanks,
I will follow github issue.

Comment: "Update 1" and "Update 2" seem contradictory. In any case, it would be better for the answer to be ***as if it was written today***, [without *"update"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011). E.g., past tense can be used for things that are no longer so. Or better version ranges (incl. release dates) for version-dependent statements. E.g., *"Prior to version 1.7.7 (2017-12-19), A, B, and C. Between version 1.7.7 and 2.4.3, D, E, and F. For version 2.4.4 or later, G, H, and I."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen issue was fixed in some preview version but then some.changes were made that lead to the issue to reappear. Improved wording.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to wait for the task to complete in order to see what is set in the **Result** property of the returned **Task** instance.

I wrote almost the same code in a console application (without the **HttpContext** parameter) and what I notice is that when you use the **Result** property in your code, the result returned by your **Foo()** method is there. It might trigger the task to wait for completion.

Link: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-task-run-async-await

Comment: `await` should take care of setting the result property.