# POST request return empty response

Tags: c#, .net, minimal-apis

I've got a minimal API with a POST request /query expecting a raw json to search in mongodb

```
app.MapPost("/query", async (HttpContext context) => await FreeQuery(context));
```

FreeQuery is async and it returns an IEnumerable.
But the async version causes internalserver error

```
async Task<IEnumerable<PreOrder>> FreeQuery(HttpContext context)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string query = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        var filter = BsonDocument.Parse(query);

        var result = _collection.Find(filter);

        var list = EnumFromBson<PreOrder>(result);

        Console.WriteLine(list.Count());

        return list;
    }
}
```

`list.Count()` returns 34 but when reading the result back on the client it's an empty string! Content-Length of the response is zero too.

How do I get a valid List back at the client?

It does work in a GET request (non async) btw

```
IEnumerable<PreOrder> FindByField(string field, string value)
{
    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq(field, value);
    var result = _collection.Find(filter);

    var list = EnumFromBson<PreOrder>(result);

    return list;
}
```

Comment: There was a bug for cases when method group calls used for handler lead to empty response - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70963719/any-idea-why-foo-returns-empty-body/70971804#70971804) but it was other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add dummy parameter to the handler:

```cs
app.MapPost("/query",
    async (HttpContext context, ILogger<Program> _) => await FreeQuery(context));
```

There [was a very similar bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70971804/2501279) (should be fixed in .NET 7) for `Map` async handlers with one `HttpContext` parameter when used via method group invocations which resulted in empty response from Minimal API endpoint. I will check later if the fix for previous issue also fixes this one.

**UPD**

Issue was not actually fixed ([github issue for .NET 7](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45373)).

Comment: yep thats it. There's 2 overloads of MapPost apparently and with 1 param the wrong one is taken. I added cancellationtoken btw which can be passed to mongodb too so it has use too