# This .NET 7 minimal API always returns 200

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, minimal-apis

I'm quite new to the concept of a minimal API, but [the documentation seems quite clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#examine-the-put-endpoint). You only have to use *Results* or *TypedResults* to return the response code you want.

So I made a very basic try:

```
app.MapPost("/api/test", async context =>
{
    var form = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
    var file = form.Files["File"];
    Results.NoContent();
});
```

But even with that, it always returns a 200 status code. I also checked a lot of other material from .NET 6 and 7 (I target .NET 7) with method delegates that have a return type of Task<IResult> as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-typedresults-api) in the documentation, but I got the same result (200). Note that I also tried returning *NotFound*, but I still got the same.

```
app.MapPost("/api/test", TestReturn);

static async Task<IResult> TestReturn(HttpContext context)
{
    var form = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
    var file = form.Files["File"];
    return TypedResults.NoContent();
}
```

Why can't I get anything else than a 200?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: For some strange reason, the result status is always 200, but if you **drop** `HttpContext context` from the argument list, result status is just as you set it. Not sure why it's that, to me it's an error. Easily reproducible.

Comment: @WiktorZychla that is a known issue - check out my answer there are some links about that.

Comment: @GuruStron: indeed, your last link is a direct description. Glad someone already posted this, I was about to search and post if not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. You forgot to use `return`:

   ```
   app.MapPost("/api/test", async context =>
   {
       var form = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
       var file = form.Files["File"];
       return Results.NoContent();
   });
   ```
2. There is a known issue with async handlers accepting `HttpContext` only, you can workaround by adding extra parameter (for example `CancellationToken`):

   ```
   app.MapPost("/api/test", async (HttpContext context, CancellationToken ct) =>
   {
       var form = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
       var file = form.Files["File"];
       return Results.NoContent();
   });
   ```

Also note that in ASP.NET Core 7 binding form files is supported [out of the box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0#file-uploads-using-iformfile-and-iformfilecollection):

```
app.MapPost("/api/test", async (IFormFileCollection files) =>
{
    var file = files["File"];
    return Results.NoContent();
});
```

See also:

- [Why does 'foo' return an empty body?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70963719/2501279)
- [POST request return empty response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74273948/2501279)
- [Minimal APIs async handlers with single HttpContext parameter are not working](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45373)

Comment: The CancellationToken was indeed the solution. I had tried the "return" before without success. And as for the IFormFile and IFormFile collection support, I knew but my real payload is multipart with string parameters and a file, which is not supported, but thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually return the result using `return`. If you don't by default `200 Ok` will be returned.

The following `Program.cs` will work and return `204 No Content` on .NET 7. I've tested it using Postman. Make sure to get the URL, port as well as HTTP method right (e.g. `GET http://localhost:5097/test`).

FYI: the project was created using `dotnet new webapi -o WebApiDemo` and then just the `Program.cs` was changed to what is shown below:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/test", () =>
{
    return TypedResults.NoContent();
});
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Comment: This still should not work for OP due to having async handler accepting `HttpContext` only