# Some minimal API endpoints not returning values, warning "ASP0016 Do not return a value from RequestDelegate"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, minimal-apis

I have the following minimal API code:

```
routeBuilder.MapGet("/test", TestMethod);
routeBuilder.MapPost("/test2", TestMethod2);

...

public static async Task<IResult> TestMethod(HttpContext http)
{
    ...
}

public static async Task<IResult> TestMethod2(HttpContext http, DataContext context, [FromForm] string value)
{
    ...
}
```

When compiling I get the warning "ASP0016 Do not return a value from RequestDelegate" of the `MapGet` with `TestMethod`. `TestMethod2` does not get this warning. Why is this happening? [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/diagnostics/asp0016?view=aspnetcore-8.0) for that warning does not explain the issue in this case at all.

Answer (score 1):

The extension method `MapGet` has two versions: one takes `Delegate` and the other `RequestDelegate`. For some reason this method is seen as the latter and it's not allowed to return any values. Implicitly casting it to `Delegate` uses the correct overload, removes the warning, and returns the correct data to the browser:

```
routeBuilder.MapGet("/test", (Delegate)TestMethod);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a "known issue" coming from the fact that async (`Task`-returning) handler functions accepting only `HttpContext` match the [`RequestDelegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.requestdelegate?view=aspnetcore-7.0) signature:

```
public delegate Task RequestDelegate(HttpContext context);
```

And the corresponding overloads are selected, so the value in the `Task<T>` returned by `TestMethod` will be ignored making Minimal APIs methods like 'MapGet'/'MapPost' etc. not working correctly.

Team is not planning to fix it ATM (or it is not easily fixable with current ASP.NET Core infrastructure) this rule was created ([ASP0016: Do not return a value from RequestDelegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/diagnostics/asp0016?view=aspnetcore-8.0)):

> Do not return a value `Delegate`s provided to APIs that expect `RequestDelegate`. For example, the following sample returns a `Task<string>` where the `string` value of the `Task` will be discarded.

There are multiple workarounds:

- Adding extra parameter so the `RequestDelegate` is not matched (`CancellationToken` is usually a good candidate):

  ```
  public static async Task<IResult> TestMethod(HttpContext http, 
       CancellationToken ct)
  ```
- Switching to another [special type binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#special-types) like `HttpRequest`:

  ```
  public static async Task<IResult> TestMethod(HttpRequest request) // add HttpResponse response if needed
  ```
- Casting to `correct` delegate type:

  ```
  routeBuilder.MapGet("/test", (Delegate)TestMethod);
  ```

More info:

- [POST request return empty response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74273948/2501279)
- [Why does 'foo' return an empty body?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70963719/2501279)
- [[Minimal APIs] async handlers with single HttpContext parameter are not working](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45373) @github
- [Minimal APIs: Moving handler with single parameter of type HttpContext to separate method results in empty response](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39956) @github